# How to bind the Selected Item to a Model with the Infragistics XamDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, infragistics

I have the following model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  public ObservableCollection<ViewElement> Elements { get; set; }

  public ViewElement CurrentElement { get; set; }
}
```

And the following grid where the parent `DataContext` is the above model:

```
<dg:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" />
```

I want to bind the `CurrentElement` property to the Selected Item of the Grid, similar to how I would in a `ListView`:

```
    <ListView x:Name="playbackSteps"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentElement}" />
```

How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: This is cross posted in the infragistics forum here: http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/24777/90741.aspx#90741

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on the [Infragistics forum](http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/24777/90741.aspx#90741), the XamDataGrid exposes an IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property.  To take advantage of this, you need a [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) of your ObservableCollection.  Something like this:

```
public ListCollectionView ElementsView {get;set;}

// In the constructor:
this.ElementsView = new ListCollectionView(Elements);
```

Then bind your XamDataGrid to ElementsView.

Comment: Putting the ListCollectionView in the ViewModel was the missing link.  I didn't want to put a WPF reference to my underlying model.  Thanks a lot.